# how to achive the below animation in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to implement the animation in the following link using flutter.
I tried the AnimatedList but it doesn't look like the following.

https://dribbble.com/shots/1355860-Gif-Animation-of-Template-Gallery

Any help or demo to implement this animation?

Answer (score 0):

This one reminds me of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html. I never had the chance to play around with it, but you can try it. Of course each folder design you have to implement it yourself, but shouldn't be that hard.